# SQL Multi part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I've come across a lot of questions about this and thought I'd understood the answers, but apparently not well enough to fix my own issue. I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select brw_pk 
from dbo.UPL
where stage = 5
AND Product = 'new'
GROUP BY brw_pk
) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT brw_pk as BRW_PK
                    , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Latest, GETDATE()) <= 60 THEN 'old'
               ELSE 'new' END   AS Selection
             , UPPER(BRW_Member_FK) as BRW_Member_FK                    
from rialto.dbo
) b
ON a.brw_pk = b.brw_pk
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT REP_PK
                             , REP_Borrowing_FK
                             , CAST(REP_PaidDate AS DATE)     AS Latest
                              ,over (PARTITION BY REP_Borrowing_FK ORDER BY REP_PaidDate DESC) AS Rnk
                        FROM Rialto.dbo.Repayment 
    
                        WHERE REP_State = 'done'
                          AND REP_Deleted = 0) REP2
                       ON REP2.REP_Borrowing_FK = b.BRW_PK
                           AND REP2.Rnk = 1
                           
WHERE brw_state in ('Withdrawn')
```

First suggestion was spelling mistakes, which I don't have. I think I'm doing something wrong related to implicit vs explicit joins, so I tried adding prefixes to Latest. Using REP2.Latest didn't fix it so I tried b for the sake of it, which of course also didn't. I tried changing the first join to an inner join, but the error is still there, and because one answer to another question suggested the order mattered (and this is left joining REP2 onto b - which I think shouldn't be a problem?) I moved the joins around. But no luck even if REP2 is the first left join.

So I've still not understood the explicit/implicit issue, I thought the prefixes would fix this, what did I miss? Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: `where stage = a`, does the table have both those columns?

Comment: Table a doesn't have the BRW_Member_FK and Latest columns, would it need them?

Comment: Columns `a` and `stage`, in the table dbo.UPL. (The first subquery.)

Comment: What I thought that line was doing was getting only the entries from dbo.UPL where the column stage contains the value a? I could also set it to be 5 for example to not be mixed up with the table alias

Comment: `a` is an identifer, in this case a column name. A string literal needs quotes, like `'a'`.

Comment: Changed it, thanks, in my code it's a number so that was a silly placeholder to use :)

Comment: `AND REP2.Rnk = 1`, but rep2 returns no Rnk column.

Comment: Oops, also fixed, my effort to make the example streamlined took out some parts. they should all be back there now.

Comment: The clause `ON REP2.REP_Borrowing_FK = b.BRW_PK` hints that you want to search for `c` rows based on the `b` rows that are found. If that's the case, a lateral join is what you need (`CROSS APPLY`).